# overload multidimensional array operator for vector

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

hi i am trying to create matrix class and i want to assign like matrix[0][2]=3 
i checked form and found a solution with array but i want to do with vector and could not understand why does not it works ?

```
 template<class T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(int a, int b)
    {
        vector<vector<T> > vec( a , vector<T> (b, 0));
        matrixData = vec;
    }
    class Array1D
    {
    public:
        Array1D(vector<T> a):temp(a) {}
        T& operator[](int a)
        {
            return temp[a];
        }
        vector<T> temp;
    };

    vector<vector<T> > matrixData;
    Array1D operator[] (int a)
    {
        return Array1D(matrixData[a]);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Matrix<int> n(3,5);
    n[0][2] = 123; //assign

    cout<<n[0][2]; // wrong output getting 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change `Array1D` implementation to:

```
class Array1D
{
public:
    Array1D(vector<T>& a):temp(a) {}
    T& operator[](int a)
    {
        return temp[a];
    }
    vector<T>& temp;
};
```

without this, every time you call `operator[]` on matrix you access temporary vector. Hence, every call `n[0]` works on different vector. So any previous modifications cannot be saved, and you always see `0` as result.

With the above change, you access original vector of matrix by `Array1D` proxy class.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qxXqdt)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the wrong type from the `Matrix::operator[]`. You need to return a nested vector by reference, so that you can chain the next `[]` to it:

```
vector<T>& operator[] (int a)
{
   return matrixData[a];
}
```

In fact, you don't need the internal `Array1D` class at all for this purpose, since `vector` already has an `operator[]`, and you can remove it entirely.

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/RnVeFK).